# Grub does not show up at start, cannot select older kernel

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

I just built a newer kernel and tried to install it. I use a script (which I have successfully used before) to that effect.

Now the kernel won't start. It shows:

```
Loading Linux <my version string>
Loading initial ramdisk
```

on a Ubuntu purple background, then switches to black screen and no more.

The strange thing is that I can't seem to access the bootloader to choose the older kernel.

I could start with an usb-live, mount the hard-drive and check `/etc/default/grub`, but I cannot run `update-grub` since it's the usb-live running.

There I could see that `<mounted_sda1>/etc/default/grub` still had `GRUB_HIDDEN` and `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT`.

How do I make the grub start prompt pop up, so that I can boot with the older kernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As inaccurate as this answer may seem, the *only* way I can get grub to show up is if I spam *right-shift* and *space-bar* just before the OS is starting to boot (just after the BIOS splash screen flashes off).

My own anecdotal efforts seem to indicate that I have the best luck when I interchange my key presses, as opposed to just spamming the 2 keys at the same time.

Having said that, I've successfully had grub show up by just *holding* the shift key, and just spamming the space-bar - it seems a bit temperamental, and it sometimes takes me a few reboots just to get it.

Comment: You got it, thanks :) . And I love (or hate) how this feels like black magic... The older kernel does not boot either, but that's for another question.

Comment: Incidentally, if you want grub to always pop up at start, edit `/etc/default/grub` with `sudo`, comment the lines starting with `GRUB_HIDDEN_`, run `sudo update-grub`, and restart.